# Datetime format to determine records order

Tags: rest, datetime, epoch

we need sending some objects from database of various types within long-polling by rest. Data are sent and each record contains timestamp. When client receive new data from server he should create another poll request with record's timestamp as parameter which helps to specify following data records.

I consider about epoch unix time and store this value in each record in database to filtering and also this value will be sent with each poll requests.

What do you think about this solution? Is that usage fine or should I worry about something? Thanks.

EDIT:

I forget notice these data will be added by clients in different time-zones. This is also another reason why I consider use unix time.

Comment: Why not use the complete timestamp of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime ? Or better, let the server include the timestamp in the data send which the client just uses as a paramter of the next request.

Comment: Your next advice is same what am I asking or not?  I also edit my question so I hope it is more clearer now.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any format of storing the timestamp is fine, as long as users will be able to unambiguously interpret it. There is no reason for timestamp format in API to be the same as in database. Idea of API is to decouple model from database.

Personally I would choose one format from  **ISO 8601 Basic and Extended Notations**. Example: **2008-09-15T15:53:00**. In virtually all programing languages there are methods to handle this format (cast to unix timestamp or to internal date/time classes). For java you would use `java.time.LocalDateTime#parse`

Unix timestamp has some issues  (they may be or not may be issues for you)

- unable to represent dates before January 1st, 1970
- unable to represent dates after January 19, 2038
- not human-readable
- does not contain timezone (timestamp itself does not have concept of timezone, but it may be useful to send client timezone along with timestamp. server may always normalise the value to UTC)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I also edit some additional information. Clients which will be send new data into server and also poll them are in different time-zones.

Comment: No matter what you choose client will be able to use any timezones. It is really matter of readability and personal taste which format you choose